# pass one tablecell variables in while loop to another class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html

Purpose: Want to show table on html web page from another class instead of code-behind class. or how to call another class instead of code-behind class?

Error on tablecell with "not all code path return a value".

mini code is at below

```
public class SQLscr : Page
{
    protected void creattable(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {           
        Table Table1 = new Table();
        TableRow r = new TableRow();
        TableCell tempc = new TableCell();;
        tempc = CreateaTable.tablecell(tempc);
        r.Cells.Add(tempc);
        Table1.Rows.Add(r);
    }
```

}

```
public class CreateaTable
```

{
   public static TableCell tablecell(TableCell c)
        {

```
        SqlDataReader myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
    while (myReader.Read()){
        c.Controls.Add(...);
        return c;
    }
```

Comment: I have to say, this looks like very inefficient code...is there a specific constraint forcing you to write it like this? typically you would do a single database call and then generate the entire table from the resultset.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
while (myReader.Read()){
    c.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(myReader["startbit_1_2_3"].ToString() + "," +
            myReader["stream_index"].ToString() + "," +)));
    return c;
}
```

I doubt you want to return on the first iteration of that loop. That's where the exception is -- there's a possibility that you might never hit that `return c` which is why it's giving you the exception that not all code paths return a value.

Move it outside the while loop.

```
while (myReader.Read()){
    c.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(myReader["startbit_1_2_3"].ToString() + "," +
            myReader["stream_index"].ToString() + "," +))); 
}
return c;
```

Comment: Amazing for the quick response. I try to return c in the outside of the while loop. However, no error and no value on html page.

Comment: @lyon819 You don't have code here for me to diagnose that issue. Please create a separate question with more context for that problem. In the meantime, if this has resolved the issue for this post, would you mind accepting my answer?

Comment: Sorry, I could not accept you as solution.
Finally, I move the while loop in the main class, and then execute the another class to return c.

sample code is at next page.

Comment: @lyon819 This answered your question about "not all code paths return a value", which is what the post was about. That's why I asked you accept the answer. Also, I see no additional sample code